# Problema com missings na variável peso em amostragem complexa

Tags: r

A presença de missings na variável peso de uma amostragem complexa está impedindo o R de calcular a média. Inicialmente tentei o `na.rm = TRUE`, porém não deu certo, segue trecho:

```
svymean(basedados$variavel , svydesign( id = basedados$estrato , weight =     
    basedados$peso ),na.rm=TRUE)
```

> Erro em na.weight(data.frame(weights)) : missing values in `weights'

Também testei esta versão e nada:

```
svymean(dp$Dcoracao , svydesign( id = dp$V0024 , weight = dp$teste , na.rm = TRUE   
    ),na.rm=TRUE)
```

> Erro em na.weight(data.frame(weights)) : missing values in `weights'

Depois foi sugerida outra forma, a qual mostra outra mensagem de erro, segue trecho:

```
svymean(bd$Dcoracao , svydesign(id = bd[which(!is.na(bd$teste)),"V0024"], weight =   
   bd[which(!is.na(bd$teste)),"teste"]))
```

> Erro em tapply(1:NROW(x), list(factor(strata)), function(index) { : 
>     arguments must have same length

Além disso: Mensagens de aviso perdidas:

1. In x * pweights :
   comprimento do objeto maior não é múltiplo do comprimento do objeto menor
2. In x * pweights :
   comprimento do objeto maior não é múltiplo do comprimento do objeto menor

Comment: Já tentou limpar a base antes de usá-la em `svymean` e `svydesign`? Declare uma variável `temp = bd[!is.na(bd$peso),]?` e então rode a pesquisa em cima desses valores.

Comment: Henrique, seria possível colocar os resultados de `summary(bd)`, `str(bd)` na sua pergunta?

Comment: @CarlosCinelli, o problema era mesmo apresença de missings na variável atribuída como Weight, já que eu tinha apenas 12 missings em 62000, transformei-os em zero e continuei. Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: @HenriquePizarro responda a sua pergunta com solução que você encontrou, para não deixar sem resposta.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli, obrigado pelo aviso, sou novo nesta comunidade.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente a variável atribuída ao parâmetro weight não pode conter missings. No meu caso em particular a base continha apenas 12 casos de 62000, portanto atribuí zero aos missings e o comando funcionou normalmente.